# ngClass seems to be working on first time load; thereafter expression is changed based on user interaction then not picking up

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular now. I learnt about `[ngClass]` directive. I want to use it for adding and removing multiple css classes. On first load it works fine. But when I change the expression variable it does not change color. I have following HTML:

```
<span [ngClass]="errorClasses">{{errorMsg}}</span>
```

and in ts:

```
public hasError = false;
public errorClasses = {
    "error" : this.hasError,
    "success" : !this.hasError,
    "italic" : true
};
```

so it renders:

```
<span class="success italic" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">Please enter Username and Password</span>
```

Then based on some user interaction I make `hasError=true`, Now I expect it to render:

```
<span class="error italic" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">Please enter Username and Password</span>
```

This is not happening; the CSS classes stays same as was in beginning.
[The entire code is available here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cv6cv50pLXh9PdyT?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1&preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is nothing to do with `ngClass` but with value update, you need to update the value of `errorClasses` with new `this.hasError` value.

Your `showError` function should look like:

```
showError(username:String, password:String) : void {
        if(username.length === 0 && password.length === 0) {
            this.errorMsg = "Please enter Username and Password";
        }
        else if(username.length) {
            this.errorMsg = "Please enter Password";
        }
        else if(password.length) {
            this.errorMsg = "Please enter Username";
        }
        this.hasError = true;
        this.errorClasses = {
        "error" : this.hasError,
        "success" : !this.hasError,
        "italic" : true
    };
```

Obvioulsly the code is not optimized and also not a good approach, its just to point you to your problem, we should not mutate the object like this

Comment: Perfect! thanks; i got what I was doing wrong `You should not mutate the object like this`; I shall accept the answer in 4 minutes